# Need help converting a p12 file to PhoneGap keystore

Tags: android, cordova, keystore, phonegap, p12

I used DevExpress tools to write a mobile app and publish the app to Google and Apple.  DevExpress has a "build native package" process which uses a p12 file to build the Android APK.  They no longer support their build tool and I'm trying to use the PhoneGap Build Service.  PhoneGap did not accept the p12

I tried a link I found here to convert the p12 to a JKS file and PhoneGap didn't like that either.
I tried generating a new keystore file and that of course didn't work.

When uploading the original p12, PhoneGap gave me this message "Error: extension .p12 did not match expected (keystore)"

Same when converting to JKS, PhoneGap gave me this message "Error: extension .jks did not match expected (keystore)"

p12 as the Android certificate. 
How do I get my p12 into a format that PhoneGap will accept?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same issue too, can you help me please?

Comment: Well, to get PhoneGap to accept the p12, it works to just change the extension from *.p12 to *.keystore.  However, I'm still having issues with the password.  Are you having issues specifically with DevExtreme like I am?  They said that internally, their build tool uses the password "tmpl"  but it didn't work for me.  Maybe it will work for you.  DevExpress support stopped helping me with the issue saying that all these problems was exactly why they dropped their build tool. :(

Comment: The password for my certificate is the one I choosen when I created it. I solved my problem with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57439739/build-phonegap-upload-or-convert-a-p12-certificate-file/57440186#57440186    What is the password problem you have?

Comment: When using DevExpress in Visual Studio, when you create the certificate, you set the password, but do not set the alias.  The alias is handled internally through DevExpress's plugin for VS.  Now, when I try to use the same cert through PhoneGap, it asks me for an alias.  DevExpress support told me the alias is "tmpl" but that doesn't work.  That cert is tied the the app on play store so I can't use a new one.

Comment: I'm not sure I used the solution you have from the link you posted, but I'll give it a go tomorrow!

Comment: With the code I posted in the link, you'll get an alias set directly from the command keytool in the output